# Twitter Bootstrap 2.0.4 Typeahead Basic Setup How to?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I am an aspiring web designer and I am learning by myself and practicing by myself. Right now I am creating a classifieds theme design.

I want to apply the twitter bootstrap js plugin typeahed, what I wanted to accomplish is just to setup the plugin and just put some dummy source data.

This is my html markup below:

```
<form class="well form-horizontal">
    <input class="city span3" type="text" data-provide="typeahead"/>
</form>
```

```
    and this is what I type for the script... bye the way, I don't have deep understanding yet about jQuery or javascript.


    $(function() {$(".city").typeahead({
            source: ["Youtube","Facebook","Yahoo"]
            })
        });
```

Comment: This is working just fine, as showed in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/R4tRB/). Do you encounter any problem or errors ? In any case, starting by a basic tutorial about javascript, then jQuery seems to be the best thing to do before going into Twitter Bootstrap plugins.

Comment: Sherbrow, thank you for pointing out that the code I've posted is working. And so, I tried to look around and see what's wrong with my markup. I have found out that a code was commented wrongfully like this <!--<script type="text/javascript">-->.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
$('.city').typeahead({
    source: ['Youtube', 'Facebook', 'Yahoo']
});
```